# 'system' to 'fork+execv' when dealing with awk command

Tags: c, awk

1)After solving the question:
  [How to translate 'system()' call to 'fork() + execl()' when dealing with awk command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083358/how-to-translate-system-call-to-fork-execl-when-dealing-with-awk-com)

2)I encounter another problem according to melpomene's method:

```
#define LOG_FILE_PATH "/tmp/logfile"
system("awk -v FS=\"[][]\" -v BEGINTIME=\"$BEGINTIME\" -v ENDTIME=\"$ENDTIME\" '$2>=BEGINTIME && $2<=ENDTIME' "LOG_FILE_PATH);
```

it works fine and I get what I want.

3)Translate to fork+execl version:

```
sprintf(tmp1, "BEGINTIME=%s", getenv("BEGINTIME"));
sprintf(tmp2, "ENDTIME=%s", getenv("ENDTIME"));
sprintf(tmp3, "$2>=%s && $2<=%s", getenv("BEGINTIME"), getenv("ENDTIME"));
execl("/usr/bin/awk", "awk", "-v", "FS=\"[][]\"", "-v", tmp1, "-v", tmp2, tmp3, LOG_FILE_PATH, (char *)0);
```

it outputs nothing, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `tmp` 3 should include the literal text `BEGINTIME` and `ENDTIME`.  Try:

```
sprintf( tmp3, "$2>=%s && $2<=%s", "BEGINTIME", "ENDTIME" );
```

Also, you probably want to keep the double quotes in `tmp1` and `tmp2`:

```
sprintf(tmp1, "BEGINTIME=\"%s\"", getenv("BEGINTIME"));
```

and you really need to check that the environment variables are actually set.

Also, you are setting FS incorrectly.  In the `system` version, `awk` gets the argument `FS=[][]` (the shell strips the double quotes before it invokes `awk`.)  So the argument passed to `execl` should be `"FS=[][]"`

Comment: I've changed to

    `sprintf(tmp3, "$2>=%s && $2<=%s", "BEGINTIME", "ENDTIME");`
but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @dejunl I just noticed that you also are setting FS incorrectly.  Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Solaris then /usr/bin/awk is old, broken awk which among it's many other issues does not support `-v` for variable assignment.

Also, awk programs are delimited by a quotation character so I THINK you should be doing something like this:

```
sprintf(tmp3, "\'$2>=%s && $2<=%s\'", ...);
```

instead of this:

```
sprintf(tmp3, "$2>=%s && $2<=%s", ...);
```

Comment: In the shell: `awk '$2>=k'` passes the literal argument `$2>=k` to awk.  (The shell strips the single quotes.)  Putting single quotes in the string passed to `exec*` would not strip the quotes.  `awk` would complain about a syntax error if you don't strip the quotes.  In other words, it would be like invoking `awk "'\$2>=k'"` from the shell.

Comment: So then does the OPs existing code result in the shell getting `awk "$2>=k"` or `awk $2>=k`? Either way $2 will be the shell positional parameter rather than a field in the input file, right?

Comment: In the existing code, the argument awk sees does not have double quotes, but it does have a literal `$`, so the `$2` refers to the file in the field.  Using `exec*`, the shell is completely out of the picture, so `$2` cannot refer to a positional parameter.

Comment: @EdMorton,@WilliamPursell Thanks for you guys' patience, your answers helped me a lot.